How can I remove this towel rail mount from my wall?
I've taken off a towel rail from my wall unscrewing the two tiny hex screws.  This is what I'm left with (x2).
Other than the hole where the box screws went in, there is no clue as to how to remove what's left without ruining the gyprock.
Does anyone have any ideas to help me please?


Any chance there is a small screw on the underside? If so, unscrew and the holder should come off

I'm fairly certain that the chrome piece screws over a flange, which is screwed to the wall.
I would get a pair of large grips around the outside and try to unscrew it, like so:


Maybe not screws, per se, but engages a couple nubs. Turn a short amount and pull. You should be able to do this by hand.

Should be by hand. Except edges look painted over.

@isherwood - could be, but I have several door-handles with similar fixings, and the chome piece screws on.

Might want to run a razor blade or knife around to cut the paint. Are you sure there isn't a little Allen screw on the bottom side?

I've seen several similar fixings where that cover plate is just a push-fit, that can be levered off. I'd still try turning it first, since that will free it up whatever type it is

I've also seen a cover plate that has a small hex screw hidden on the bottom edge so it isn't visible. Worth double checking there as well to make sure one wasn't overlooked.

Could also be a simple press fit.

It could lift upwards parallel to the wall to remove it.
Imagine a small rail that it slots over/into.
If it moves up with a tap from a block of wood (or something else with a bit of weight that won't damage the surface), then keep going.
